# Regarding to not calling of enquiry.cs in app code

Tags: asp.net, .net

I am a newcomer in .net , my problem is related to email. This code is well performed on my localhost. This is code of my enquiry.aspx.cs:-

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    Mail mm = new Mail();
    if (DropDownList3.SelectedItem.Text == "--Select--")
    {
        Label5.Text = "Please Select Course";
        //Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "Error", "alert('Please Enter Name');", true);
        //Response.Write("<script language=JavaScript> alert('Please Enter Name'); </script>");

    }
    else if (TextBox1.Text == "")
    {
        Label5.Text = "Please Enter Name";
        //Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "Error", "alert('Please Enter Name');", true);
        //Response.Write("<script language=JavaScript> alert('Please Enter Name'); </script>");
        TextBox1.Focus();
    }
    else if (mm.checkValidemail(TextBox2.Text) == false)
    {
        Label5.Text = "Please Enter E-Mail ID";
        //Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "Error", "alert('Please Enter E-Mail ID');", true);
        //Response.Write("<script language=JavaScript> alert('Please Enter E-Mail ID'); </script>");
        TextBox2.Focus();
    }
    else if (mm.checkValidmobile(TextBox3.Text) == false)
    {
        Label5.Text = "Please Enter Mobile Number";
        //Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "Error", "alert('Please Enter Mobile Number');", true);
        //Response.Write("<script language=JavaScript> alert('Please Enter Mobile Number'); </script>");
        TextBox3.Focus();
    }


    else
    {
        myenquiry ee = new myenquiry();
       //myenquiry ee=new myenquiry();
       int i = ee.add_enquiry(TextBox1.Text, TextBox2.Text, TextBox3.Text, TextBox4.Text, TextBox5.Text, "-", "-", "NORMAL ENQUIRY FROM SITE", TextBox11.Text, DropDownList3.SelectedItem.Text, TextBox12.Text,locationlst.SelectedItem.Text);
        if (i == 1)
        {

            MailMessage message = new MailMessage();

            message.From = new MailAddress(" Enquiry " + "<shila@gmail.com> ");
            message.To.Add(new MailAddress("shu@gmail.com"));
            message.CC.Add(new MailAddress("va_aone@yahoo.com"));
            message.Subject = "Enquiry from CMC site";
            string p = "<b>Name: </b>" + TextBox1.Text;
            p += "<br><b>Mobile:</b> " + TextBox3.Text;
            p += "<br><b>Mail ID:</b> " + TextBox2.Text;
            p += "<br><b>Address:</b> " + TextBox4.Text;
            p += "<br><b>City:</b> " + TextBox5.Text;
            p += "<br><b>Location:</b>" + locationlst.SelectedItem.Text;
            p += "<br><b>College:</b> " + TextBox11.Text;
            p += "<br><b>Course:</b> " + DropDownList3.SelectedItem.Text;

            p += "<br><b>Query:</b> " + TextBox12.Text;
            message.Body = p;
            message.IsBodyHtml = true;

            SmtpClient SMTPServer = new SmtpClient("localhost");
            try
            {
                SMTPServer.Send(message);
                //result = "Your Enquiry has been Submitted !!";
                Label5.Text = "Your Enquiry has been Submitted !!";
                //Response.Write("<script language=JavaScript> alert('Your Enquiry has been Submitted !!'); </script>");
                TextBox1.Text = "";
                TextBox2.Text = "";
                TextBox3.Text = "";
                TextBox4.Text = "";
                TextBox5.Text = "";
                TextBox11.Text = "";
                TextBox12.Text = "";
                DropDownList3.SelectedIndex = 0;

            }
            catch
            {
               Label5.Text = "Server Problem !!Your Enquiry Not Submitted";


              //Response.Write("<script language=JavaScript> alert('Server Problem !!Your Enquiry Not Submitted'); </script>");
            }
        }
        else
        {
            Label5.Text = "Server Problem !!Your Enquiry Not Submitted";
        }
    }
```

and this is my appcode folder enquiry.cs:-

```
public class myenquiry
{ 
    SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection("Data Source=USER-PC;Initial Catalog=group;Integrated Security=True");
    SqlCommand comm = new SqlCommand();
    int result = 0;
    public int add_enquiry(string nam,string email,string mob,string adr,string cit,string state,string country,string zip,string college,string tech,string query,string loc)
    {
        try
        {
            comm.Connection = conn;
            comm.CommandText = "insert into enquiry(name,email,mobile,address,city,state,country,zip,college,technology,query,edate,location) values('" + nam + "','" + email + "','" + mob + "','" + adr + "','" + cit + "','" + state + "','" + country + "','" + zip + "','" + college + "','" + tech + "','" + query + "','" + DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd") + "','"+loc+"')";
            conn.Open();
            comm.ExecuteNonQuery();
            result = 1;
        }
        catch(Exception ee)
        {
            result = 0;
        }
        finally
        {
            conn.Close();
        }
        return result;
    }
}
```

this is well perform on local. But at the server the appcode enquiry.cs is not called on enquiry.aspx.cs and the value of `int i` is becoming 0, so the else part is executing. Why?

Answer (score 0):

You seem to have a hard coded connection string in the `myenquiry` class. If you are not dynamically setting the connection string from a configuration file or otherwise, the insert method will try to use that string which points to your local. Assuming your server is a different domain/machine with no access to your local DB, the connection will definitely fail, giving you the result 0.

Answer (score 0):

As Shree.pat18 says Don't make hardcodded connection string in class file.instead of this make your connection string in web.config file something like this in your configuration tag

```
<connectionStrings>
 <add name="cn" connectionString="Data Source=USER-PC;Initial Catalog=group;Integrated Security=True"/>
</connectionStrings>
```